# How can I get logType and level from Json ElasticSearch by using Nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to get value of loglevel and logType from below json logs of ElasticSearch by using Nest Code. LogLevel should be "ERROR" LogType should be "Response". How can I write this Nest query. I think that Nest is Really difficult.

```
        var settings = new connectionsettings(new uri("http://localhost:9200")).defaultındex("mylog-2019-07-29");

        var client = new elasticclient(settings);

        var searchresponse = client.search<rootobject>(s => s
                                        .allındices()
                                        .from(0)
                                        .size(10)
                                        .query(q => q
                                             .match(m => m
                                                .field(f => f.logLevel)
                                                .query("Error")
                                             )
                                        ));

        var r3 = client.search<rootobject>(search => search.matchall().ındex("mylog-2019-07-29")).documents;

        // OR 
        var result = client.search<rootobject>(q => q.allındices());
        var result2 = result.hits;

        using (httpclient client = new httpclient())
        {
            var result = await client.getasync("http://localhost:9200");

            var data = jsonconvert.deserializeobject<list<rootobject>>(result.content.readasstringasync().result);

        }
```

How can I do that with below json?

```py
{
  "took": 72,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2968679,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "slog-2019-07-29",
        "_type": "logmessage",
        "_id": "335af90f-6dab-459d-95f2-df09ffb15380",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "335af90f-6dab-459d-95f2-df09ffb15380",
          "parentLogId": "3ccf12bb-028e-498d-bc04-1394746c1d6f",
          "logDate": "2019-07-29T11:05:04.0554493Z",
          "logLevel": "Information",
          "logSource": "TourService",
          "logType": "Response",
          "environment": "Production",
          "sessionId": null,
          "traceId": "d6dc979e-4ce6-4c16-8f8a-7ed41c1cd87a",
          "klm": null,
          "data": "{\"isSuccess\":true,\"code\":null,\"message\":null,\"data\":{\"xxxx\":{\"provider\":0,\......\"xxxxxxxx\":0.0}]}]}}}",
          "processCost": 107.6808,
          "urlMethod": "POST",
          "urlPath": "/api/tour/get",
          "urlQueryString": null,
          "responseStatusCode": 200,
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Content-Type",
              "value": [
                "application/json; charset=utf-8"
              ]
            },
            {
              "key": "Request-Context",
              "value": [
                "appId=cid-v1:ec6df344-e1df-4097-bef4-69a3cce06eb6"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "additionalData": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "slog-2019-07-29",
        "_type": "logmessage",

        .....
        ....
        ..
        .
```

My Index MAP:

```py
{
    "slog-2019-07-29": {
        "mappings": {
            "logmessage": {
                "properties": {
                    "additionalData": {
                        "properties": {
                            "data": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "method": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "url": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "caller": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "correlationId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "environment": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "properties": {
                            "key": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "value": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "logDate": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "logLevel": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "logSource": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "logType": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "parentLogId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "processCost": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "responseStatusCode": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "urlMethod": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "urlPath": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "urlQueryString": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of NEST and elasticsearch do you use? Could you share index mapping?

Comment: Hi I am using Last version of Nest.

Comment: You can get index mapping by typing `http://localhost:9200/slog-2019-07-29/_mapping` into your browser.

Comment: @Rob I updated my question with my index mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to get back documents with exact value in the field, you need to use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html). So this elasticsearch query will work for you:

```
GET slog-2019-07-29/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "logLevel.keyword": {
        "value": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that for the field I used `logLevel.keyword` instead of `logLevel` this is because `logLevel.keyword` field is of type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) which is very useful in your case because elasticsearch doesn't analyse value in such fields, so `Information` is saved in elasticsearch as `Information`. That will allow you to find documents with exact value in specific fields. For `logLevel` field which is of type `text` that is saved as `information`.

We also need to use a term query because we don't want elasticsearch to analyse what we have put into `value`.

Now, with the NEST you can write such query with the following code:

```
var searchResponse = await elasticClient
    .SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Term(t => t
                .Field(f => f.LogLevel.Suffix("keyword"))
                .Value("Information"))));

class Document
{
    public string LogLevel { get; set; }
}
```

> LogLevel should be "ERROR" LogType should be "Response".

For this, you would need to use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) which will allow you to combine multiple conditions into one query.

```
GET slog-2019-07-29/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "logLevel.keyword": {
              "value": "ERROR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "logType.keyword": {
              "value": "Response"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

NEST has a really nice section in docs on [how to build bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-query-usage.html), so I'll leave it for you as an exercise.

Also, I encourage you to read [Elasticsearch: The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index.html) which will give you a great overview of basics and how things work in elasticserch.

Hope that helps.